# Sharing OneNote 2010? Desktop and Laptop and the Web(Skydrive)?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I love Onenote and have 2010.
I've been able to sync Onenote on my laptop and skydrive, but would like to add a desktop with the onenote client to to sync with as well (not use web).

Onenote will only give me two choices for sync: a)web or b)network. I can't do both.

Does anyone have any solutions on how I can sync all 3, and be able to edit on all 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, create a new notebook.
Choose to save it on the web (SkyDrive).

Then, switch to your laptop.
**Create a new notebook with the exact same name and parent folder**.
OneNote will tell you that a notebook already exists.
And you can choose to use that folder as a new notebook.

OR

from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/share-notebooks-in-onenote-2010-HA010386952.aspx

> If you won't be sharing your notebook with others but you want to use it on multiple computers, you can click E-mail a Link and then send the e-mail message with the link to your own Web-based e-mail account. This way, you can easily open the shared notebook from another computer.

This should solve your problem

Comment: +1 for Web(skydrive). Skydrive also allows for concurrent edits.

Answer (score 2):

if the 2010 notebook is shared to web copy (skydrive), 
and you wish to have a local back up copy, 
then the only way I've found is to manually save a copy (save as) occasionally locally.

Otherwise I haven't found  way to also sync to a local copy.
(Onenote must have a local copy someone because I can use it offline also, perhaps in app data somewhere?, so it should be recoverable somehow)

This is for those who don't like having all their note data stored on the web and want to know there's a back up should Skydrive take a dive.

For One Note 2007 users, 
Live mesh will only save a copy to your 'device' folder on the skydrive if you try to be more old school, which unfortunately is not accessible from your mobile via Micrososft apps (for those trying to sync Onenote accross their pc and mobile through skydrive.

Also, to sync to mobile, you need OneNote 2010 (2007 won't work).

Hope that helps someone.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

A more general solution would be to use a file syncing service (like dropbox) to sync the files between the computers

[dropbox (referral link)](http://db.tt/rb95DiD)

Comment: Microsoft Live is a better option.  Not only is it more storage (2GB vs 5GB) but also allows concurrent editing among users or other machines.

Comment: Do you mean the service formerly called 'live mesh'? This was my preferred service till recently, but dropping the XP client support made it unsuitable for some clients (like me)