# SkyDrive Notebook not syncing as expected

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, onedrive

I've been using OneNote for about a year and a half now (if only I had known about it while I was at university!) and just got SkyDrive a week ago. I've begun the task of moving all of my Notebooks to SkyDrive using several ways to see which would work the best. All of the Notebooks are currently stored on my flash, and I access them on two different computers on a daily basis.

For `Notebook1`, I used `Change Location` in its properties to physically move the Notebook folder from my flash to the SkyDrive folder on `Computer1`. After the SkyDrive app finished syncing, I logged into SkyDrive via the browser and found the `Notebook1` folder with all its subfolders and sections, as expected.

For `Notebook2`, I used the `Share` command to place a link to it on SkyDrive from `Computer2`. After the Skydrive app finished syncing, I logged into SkyDrive via the browser and found a single OneNote page called `Notebook2`.

Once the SkyDrive app has finished downloading the files to the SkyDrive folder on `Computer2`, I can open `Notebook1` on `Computer2` from the local SkyDrive folder. On `Computer1`, if I try to open `Notebook2`, it gives an error saying it is a system file and cannot be opened. Opening it in the browser opens the OneNote Web App. `Notebook2` is also no longer syncing changes with SkyDrive. Note that I do not have the luxury of syncing whenever I want due to, let's call it "internet connectivity challenges" in this part of the world, although currently the connection is stable.

Now the question: I want my NoteBooks to be portable, which is why I keep them on my flash. But flashes can be easily corrupted, I don't want the physical location of the Notebooks to be the SkyDrive folder, and I don't want to use the `Share` command because I want the whole Notebook to be available, and not just to open via the Web App. At the end of each day, I want the NoteBooks to be in sync on `Computer1`, `Computer2` and SkyDrive. How can I achieve this?

Note: I have been playing around with OneNote 2013 Preview, so it's possible that the sharing features have improved. I've also taken a look at the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/237441/sharing-onenote-2010-desktop-and-laptop-and-the-webskydrive), but it's not exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Move location of notebook to SkyDrive folder
2. Close notebook and OneNote
3. Let SkyDrive sync
4. Open Notebook from SkyDrive folder
5. Notebook downloads onto local machine, and physical folder changes to an Internet shortcut

So the best way is to open the notebook directly from the SkyDrive dialog within OneNote.